# how to convert tuple to comma seperated string in pig

Tags: apache-pig

How do I convert a tuple to string in PIG?

e.g. change

```
{("Lost"),("Law and Order")}
```

to

```
"Lost, Law and Order"
```

FOREACH my_programs GENERATE ...

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey...better create an udf to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can have only two fields in my_programs, you can use CONCAT. Otherwise you should create a custom UDF.

```
FOREACH my_programs GENERATE
CONCAT($0, CONCAT(', ', $1));
```